# Do all versions of SimCity 3000 have the same advisors?

Tags: version-differences, simcity-3000

I understand some European releases of the game at least replaced the safety advisor and the Health/Education advisor (upon some research seemingly to get a more representative ethnic distribution?)

Can anyone name these specific advisors for me, and are there any other alternate advisors for SimCity 3K used around the world?